# urllib3 failure through Apache/WSGI; successful from python commandline

Tags: apache-2.4, http, python, django, mod-wsgi

I have a webserver serving `Django` through `Apache 2.4` with `mod_wsgi` and `Python 2.7` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.  When first setup, outgoing connections from this webserver using the `Python` library `urllib3` were successful.  Currently, outgoing connections using urllib3 are possible using the Python command line client, but the Apache server is failing them with Error 0 after hitting it's maximum retries.  I am unsure of what recent changes may have caused the issue.

Are there any recommended techniques for diagnosing and addressing Apache's sudden inability to conduct outgoing requests with `urllib3`?